# Shortest distance between two line segments

Tags: language-agnostic, geometry

I need a function to find the shortest distance between two line segments. A line segment is defined by two endpoints. So for example one of my line segments (AB) would be defined by the two points A (x1,y1) and B (x2,y2) and the other (CD) would be defined by the two points C (x1,y1) and D (x2,y2).

Feel free to write the solution in any language you want and I can translate it into javascript. Please keep in mind my geometry skills are pretty rusty. I have already seen [here](http://stochastix.wordpress.com/2008/12/28/distance-between-two-lines/) and I am not sure how to translate this into a function. Thank you so much for help.

Comment: [here's a link to a similar question and the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541150/connect-two-line-segments/11427699#11427699).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this in 2 dimensions? If so, the answer is simply the shortest of the distance between point A and line segment CD, B and CD, C and AB or D and AB. So it's a fairly simple "distance between point and line" calculation (if the distances are all the same, then the lines are parallel).

[This site explains the algorithm for distance between a point and a line pretty well.](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/)

It's slightly more tricky in the 3 dimensions because the lines are not necessarily in the same plane, but that doesn't seem to be the case here?

Comment: But if the segments intersect, the minimum distance between each endpoint and its opposite segment could still be nonzero....or have I misunderstood the problem?

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that particular case :) If they intersect then obviously the minimum distance is 0. Paul Bourke to the rescue again: http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/lineline2d/

Comment: Yes codeka this is in 2D. I was thinking there was something more elegant than having to repeat distance check four times. But this makes sense and I accept this answer.

Comment: Either I'm missing something or the algorithm will not work for (0,0)-(1,0) and (2,1)-(2,2). Correct distance is sqrt(2) and the algorithm will give 1.

Comment: @maxim1000: In my description, "AB" represents the line segment A->B, I've edited to make that clear. If you go to the site I linked to (I've also updated the link, it looks like it's moved) you can see the algorithm for distance between a point and a line is actually very similar to the algorithm for the distance between a point and a line segment (i.e. you just limit the value of `u` to the range [0,1]).

Comment: @DeanHarding should add more information to the answer rather than to the comments to get my up-vote.  Perhaps explain how you would constrain the ends, which is not terribly hard, but it is not trivial.

Comment: Have you got the solution for line segments in the third dimension? (Python)

Comment: @DeanHarding your link is broken, in the comment above

Comment: This is nice Dr. Dean Harding, but no code means no points ;)  J/k I upvoted.  I will be posting some python code that does this very algorithm for PyQt5 QVector2D's.

Comment: this wont work.. as you can have the perpendicular distance between two lines being close but the endpoints of the target line being far

Answer (score 44):

This is my solution in Python. Works with 3d points and you can simplify for 2d.

```py
import numpy as np

def closestDistanceBetweenLines(a0,a1,b0,b1,clampAll=False,clampA0=False,clampA1=False,clampB0=False,clampB1=False):

    ''' Given two lines defined by numpy.array pairs (a0,a1,b0,b1)
        Return the closest points on each segment and their distance
    '''

    # If clampAll=True, set all clamps to True
    if clampAll:
        clampA0=True
        clampA1=True
        clampB0=True
        clampB1=True


    # Calculate denomitator
    A = a1 - a0
    B = b1 - b0
    magA = np.linalg.norm(A)
    magB = np.linalg.norm(B)
    
    _A = A / magA
    _B = B / magB
    
    cross = np.cross(_A, _B);
    denom = np.linalg.norm(cross)**2
    
    
    # If lines are parallel (denom=0) test if lines overlap.
    # If they don't overlap then there is a closest point solution.
    # If they do overlap, there are infinite closest positions, but there is a closest distance
    if not denom:
        d0 = np.dot(_A,(b0-a0))
        
        # Overlap only possible with clamping
        if clampA0 or clampA1 or clampB0 or clampB1:
            d1 = np.dot(_A,(b1-a0))
            
            # Is segment B before A?
            if d0 <= 0 >= d1:
                if clampA0 and clampB1:
                    if np.absolute(d0) < np.absolute(d1):
                        return a0,b0,np.linalg.norm(a0-b0)
                    return a0,b1,np.linalg.norm(a0-b1)
                
                
            # Is segment B after A?
            elif d0 >= magA <= d1:
                if clampA1 and clampB0:
                    if np.absolute(d0) < np.absolute(d1):
                        return a1,b0,np.linalg.norm(a1-b0)
                    return a1,b1,np.linalg.norm(a1-b1)
                
                
        # Segments overlap, return distance between parallel segments
        return None,None,np.linalg.norm(((d0*_A)+a0)-b0)
        
    
    
    # Lines criss-cross: Calculate the projected closest points
    t = (b0 - a0);
    detA = np.linalg.det([t, _B, cross])
    detB = np.linalg.det([t, _A, cross])

    t0 = detA/denom;
    t1 = detB/denom;

    pA = a0 + (_A * t0) # Projected closest point on segment A
    pB = b0 + (_B * t1) # Projected closest point on segment B


    # Clamp projections
    if clampA0 or clampA1 or clampB0 or clampB1:
        if clampA0 and t0 < 0:
            pA = a0
        elif clampA1 and t0 > magA:
            pA = a1
        
        if clampB0 and t1 < 0:
            pB = b0
        elif clampB1 and t1 > magB:
            pB = b1
            
        # Clamp projection A
        if (clampA0 and t0 < 0) or (clampA1 and t0 > magA):
            dot = np.dot(_B,(pA-b0))
            if clampB0 and dot < 0:
                dot = 0
            elif clampB1 and dot > magB:
                dot = magB
            pB = b0 + (_B * dot)
    
        # Clamp projection B
        if (clampB0 and t1 < 0) or (clampB1 and t1 > magB):
            dot = np.dot(_A,(pB-a0))
            if clampA0 and dot < 0:
                dot = 0
            elif clampA1 and dot > magA:
                dot = magA
            pA = a0 + (_A * dot)

    
    return pA,pB,np.linalg.norm(pA-pB)
```

Test example with pictures to help visualize:

```py
a1=np.array([13.43, 21.77, 46.81])
a0=np.array([27.83, 31.74, -26.60])
b0=np.array([77.54, 7.53, 6.22])
b1=np.array([26.99, 12.39, 11.18])

closestDistanceBetweenLines(a0,a1,b0,b1,clampAll=True)
# Result: (array([ 20.29994362,  26.5264818 ,  11.78759994]), array([ 26.99,  12.39,  11.18]), 15.651394495590445) # 
closestDistanceBetweenLines(a0,a1,b0,b1,clampAll=False)
# Result: (array([ 19.85163563,  26.21609078,  14.07303667]), array([ 18.40058604,  13.21580716,  12.02279907]), 13.240709703623198) #
```

[image: Closest point between two lines]
[image: Closest point between two lines segments]

Comment: This example computes the distance between two lines, not between two line segments...

Comment: @user989762 thanks for pointing this out, I made appropriate correction. See edit above.

Comment: This seems to return None if the segments are parallel.   This seems like an incomplete solution.  Two parallel segments still have a minimum distance between them.  You can also return two points.  In a one class of cases -- like (0,0)-(1,0) and (0,1)-(1,1) -- there are infinitely many pairs of valid points, and you can choose two.  For the rest -- like (0,0)-(0,1) and (3,1)-(4,1) -- the two points are unique.  Care to update it?

Comment: @D.A. good catch i edited the code to handle that situation. Works with clamp as well so it'll return the proper points if one segment is ahead or behind the other.

Comment: Hello. IMO this does not work correctly with clampAll=True. Check this graph https://imagebin.ca/v/37Q59DkrvSkb generated using this GNUPlot script http://pastebin.com/9fUPernA IMO minimal distance line should not go from end of purple line (rotate it in GNUPlot if you can to see it yourself).

Comment: @jhutar thanks for the catch, I added clamping as an afterthought and obviously didn't test thoroughly. I addressed the bug and it should now produce the result you'd expect.

Comment: I converted the code to C# in case anyone else needs it: https://pastebin.com/CAPBDCFZ It assumes a Vector3 class such as the one defined in Unity3D

Comment: I've just tested the output from the script and I'm getting completely different output compared to the example numbers?

Comment: @DanielRichardson sorry about that, i updated the code at some point and forgot to update the example values. Everything should be right and i verified on my machine that the values projections were correct.

Comment: @Fnord, what library are you using for generating the picture to visualize of the points and lines in 3D?

Comment: @A.Sommerh it’s a 3D scene built in Autodesk Maya. And I use mpynode (www.mpynode.com) to run the python code in real time. The images are screen grabs.

Comment: You may need to adjust the comparisons by a small value to deal with floating point errors (I did when porting to Perl). For example, `if t0 < 0` might be `if t0 < 1e-6`.

Answer (score 13):

Taken from [this example](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_distance_segment_to_segment.html), which also comes with a simple explanation of why it works as well as VB code (that does more than you need, so I've simplified as I translated to Python -- note: I have translated, but not tested, so a typo might have slipped by...):

```py
def segments_distance(x11, y11, x12, y12, x21, y21, x22, y22):
  """ distance between two segments in the plane:
      one segment is (x11, y11) to (x12, y12)
      the other is   (x21, y21) to (x22, y22)
  """
  if segments_intersect(x11, y11, x12, y12, x21, y21, x22, y22): return 0
  # try each of the 4 vertices w/the other segment
  distances = []
  distances.append(point_segment_distance(x11, y11, x21, y21, x22, y22))
  distances.append(point_segment_distance(x12, y12, x21, y21, x22, y22))
  distances.append(point_segment_distance(x21, y21, x11, y11, x12, y12))
  distances.append(point_segment_distance(x22, y22, x11, y11, x12, y12))
  return min(distances)

def segments_intersect(x11, y11, x12, y12, x21, y21, x22, y22):
  """ whether two segments in the plane intersect:
      one segment is (x11, y11) to (x12, y12)
      the other is   (x21, y21) to (x22, y22)
  """
  dx1 = x12 - x11
  dy1 = y12 - y11
  dx2 = x22 - x21
  dy2 = y22 - y21
  delta = dx2 * dy1 - dy2 * dx1
  if delta == 0: return False  # parallel segments
  s = (dx1 * (y21 - y11) + dy1 * (x11 - x21)) / delta
  t = (dx2 * (y11 - y21) + dy2 * (x21 - x11)) / (-delta)
  return (0 <= s <= 1) and (0 <= t <= 1)

import math
def point_segment_distance(px, py, x1, y1, x2, y2):
  dx = x2 - x1
  dy = y2 - y1
  if dx == dy == 0:  # the segment's just a point
    return math.hypot(px - x1, py - y1)

  # Calculate the t that minimizes the distance.
  t = ((px - x1) * dx + (py - y1) * dy) / (dx * dx + dy * dy)

  # See if this represents one of the segment's
  # end points or a point in the middle.
  if t < 0:
    dx = px - x1
    dy = py - y1
  elif t > 1:
    dx = px - x2
    dy = py - y2
  else:
    near_x = x1 + t * dx
    near_y = y1 + t * dy
    dx = px - near_x
    dy = py - near_y

  return math.hypot(dx, dy)
```

Comment: There is a typo in the initial 'if segments_intersect' condition on line 6.  It should be '...x22, y22): return 0' not '...y22, y22); return 0'.  Also, be wary of integer math vs. floating point math.  Thanks for the code snippet, besides the bugs, worked for me!

Comment: Thanks, this was useful *and* educational. I thought it was more advanced, but then I realized that at least one of the line endpoints always has to be the closest point to the other, making it just a matter of multiple point2line calculations. It might need a special-case handling for distances between paralell lines though. I used a modified version of this code that also returns the closest points along the lines in my [Shapy geometry package](http://thepythongischallenge.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/shapy-a-new-pure-python-shapely-in-the-works/) for Python.

Answer (score 9):

This is my solution. It's programmed in Lua. It is very concise, so maybe it will be appreciated. Please do make sure the lengths of the line segments are non 0.

```lua
local eta = 1e-6
local function nearestPointsOnLineSegments(a0, a1, b0, b1)
    local r = b0 - a0
    local u = a1 - a0
    local v = b1 - b0

    local ru = r:Dot(u)
    local rv = r:Dot(v)
    local uu = u:Dot(u)
    local uv = u:Dot(v)
    local vv = v:Dot(v)

    local det = uu*vv - uv*uv
    local s, t

    if det < eta*uu*vv then
        s = math.clamp(ru/uu, 0, 1)
        t = 0
    else
        s = math.clamp((ru*vv - rv*uv)/det, 0, 1)
        t = math.clamp((ru*uv - rv*uu)/det, 0, 1)
    end

    local S = math.clamp((t*uv + ru)/uu, 0, 1)
    local T = math.clamp((s*uv - rv)/vv, 0, 1)

    local A = a0 + S*u
    local B = b0 + T*v
    return A, B, (B - A):Length()
end
```

Comment: very elegant solution.  Got my upvote.  Thank you for posting.

Comment: I asked ChatGPT to port this to python and it worked on the first try! Nice work.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is a translation of Fnord solution. I do in javascript and C.

In Javascript. You need to include [mathjs](http://mathjs.org).

```
var closestDistanceBetweenLines = function(a0, a1, b0, b1, clampAll, clampA0, clampA1, clampB0, clampB1){
    //Given two lines defined by numpy.array pairs (a0,a1,b0,b1)
    //Return distance, the two closest points, and their average

    clampA0 = clampA0 || false;
    clampA1 = clampA1 || false;
    clampB0 = clampB0 || false;
    clampB1 = clampB1 || false;
    clampAll = clampAll || false;

    if(clampAll){
        clampA0 = true;
        clampA1 = true;
        clampB0 = true;
        clampB1 = true;
    }

    //Calculate denomitator
    var A = math.subtract(a1, a0);
    var B = math.subtract(b1, b0);
    var _A = math.divide(A, math.norm(A))
    var _B = math.divide(B, math.norm(B))
    var cross = math.cross(_A, _B);
    var denom = math.pow(math.norm(cross), 2);

    //If denominator is 0, lines are parallel: Calculate distance with a projection and evaluate clamp edge cases
    if (denom == 0){
        var d0 = math.dot(_A, math.subtract(b0, a0));
        var d = math.norm(math.subtract(math.add(math.multiply(d0, _A), a0), b0));

        //If clamping: the only time we'll get closest points will be when lines don't overlap at all. Find if segments overlap using dot products.
        if(clampA0 || clampA1 || clampB0 || clampB1){
            var d1 = math.dot(_A, math.subtract(b1, a0));

            //Is segment B before A?
            if(d0 <= 0 && 0 >= d1){
                if(clampA0 == true && clampB1 == true){
                    if(math.absolute(d0) < math.absolute(d1)){
                        return [b0, a0, math.norm(math.subtract(b0, a0))];                       
                    }
                    return [b1, a0, math.norm(math.subtract(b1, a0))];
                }
            }
            //Is segment B after A?
            else if(d0 >= math.norm(A) && math.norm(A) <= d1){
                if(clampA1 == true && clampB0 == true){
                    if(math.absolute(d0) < math.absolute(d1)){
                        return [b0, a1, math.norm(math.subtract(b0, a1))];
                    }
                    return [b1, a1, math.norm(math.subtract(b1,a1))];
                }
            }

        }

        //If clamping is off, or segments overlapped, we have infinite results, just return position.
        return [null, null, d];
    }

    //Lines criss-cross: Calculate the dereminent and return points
    var t = math.subtract(b0, a0);
    var det0 = math.det([t, _B, cross]);
    var det1 = math.det([t, _A, cross]);

    var t0 = math.divide(det0, denom);
    var t1 = math.divide(det1, denom);

    var pA = math.add(a0, math.multiply(_A, t0));
    var pB = math.add(b0, math.multiply(_B, t1));

    //Clamp results to line segments if needed
    if(clampA0 || clampA1 || clampB0 || clampB1){

        if(t0 < 0 && clampA0)
            pA = a0;
        else if(t0 > math.norm(A) && clampA1)
            pA = a1;

        if(t1 < 0 && clampB0)
            pB = b0;
        else if(t1 > math.norm(B) && clampB1)
            pB = b1;

    }

    var d = math.norm(math.subtract(pA, pB))

    return [pA, pB, d];
}
//example
var a1=[13.43, 21.77, 46.81];
var a0=[27.83, 31.74, -26.60];
var b0=[77.54, 7.53, 6.22];
var b1=[26.99, 12.39, 11.18];
closestDistanceBetweenLines(a0,a1,b0,b1,true);
```

In pure C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double determinante3(double* a, double* v1, double* v2){
    return a[0] * (v1[1] * v2[2] - v1[2] * v2[1]) + a[1] * (v1[2] * v2[0] - v1[0] * v2[2]) + a[2] * (v1[0] * v2[1] - v1[1] * v2[0]);
}

double* cross3(double* v1, double* v2){
    double* v = (double*)malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
    v[0] = v1[1] * v2[2] - v1[2] * v2[1];
    v[1] = v1[2] * v2[0] - v1[0] * v2[2];
    v[2] = v1[0] * v2[1] - v1[1] * v2[0];
    return v;
}

double dot3(double* v1, double* v2){
    return v1[0] * v2[0] + v1[1] * v2[1] + v1[2] * v2[2];
}

double norma3(double* v1){
    double soma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        soma += pow(v1[i], 2);
    }
    return sqrt(soma);
}

double* multiplica3(double* v1, double v){
    double* v2 = (double*)malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        v2[i] = v1[i] * v;
    }
    return v2;
}

double* soma3(double* v1, double* v2, int sinal){
    double* v = (double*)malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        v[i] = v1[i] + sinal * v2[i];
    }
    return v;
}

Result_distance* closestDistanceBetweenLines(double* a0, double* a1, double* b0, double* b1, int clampAll, int clampA0, int clampA1, int clampB0, int clampB1){
    double denom, det0, det1, t0, t1, d;
    double *A, *B, *_A, *_B, *cross, *t, *pA, *pB;
    Result_distance *rd = (Result_distance *)malloc(sizeof(Result_distance));

    if (clampAll){
        clampA0 = 1;
        clampA1 = 1;
        clampB0 = 1;
        clampB1 = 1;
    }

    A = soma3(a1, a0, -1);
    B = soma3(b1, b0, -1);
    _A = multiplica3(A, 1 / norma3(A));
    _B = multiplica3(B, 1 / norma3(B));
    cross = cross3(_A, _B);
    denom = pow(norma3(cross), 2);

    if (denom == 0){
        double d0 = dot3(_A, soma3(b0, a0, -1));
        d = norma3(soma3(soma3(multiplica3(_A, d0), a0, 1), b0, -1));
        if (clampA0 || clampA1 || clampB0 || clampB1){
            double d1 = dot3(_A, soma3(b1, a0, -1));
            if (d0 <= 0 && 0 >= d1){
                if (clampA0 && clampB1){
                    if (abs(d0) < abs(d1)){
                        rd->pA = b0;
                        rd->pB = a0;
                        rd->d = norma3(soma3(b0, a0, -1));
                    }
                    else{
                        rd->pA = b1;
                        rd->pB = a0;
                        rd->d = norma3(soma3(b1, a0, -1));
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (d0 >= norma3(A) && norma3(A) <= d1){
                if (clampA1 && clampB0){
                    if (abs(d0) <abs(d1)){
                        rd->pA = b0;
                        rd->pB = a1;
                        rd->d = norma3(soma3(b0, a1, -1));
                    }
                    else{
                        rd->pA = b1;
                        rd->pB = a1;
                        rd->d = norma3(soma3(b1, a1, -1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            rd->pA = NULL;
            rd->pB = NULL;
            rd->d = d;
        }
    }
    else{
        t = soma3(b0, a0, -1);
        det0 = determinante3(t, _B, cross);
        det1 = determinante3(t, _A, cross);
        t0 = det0 / denom;
        t1 = det1 / denom;
        pA = soma3(a0, multiplica3(_A, t0), 1);
        pB = soma3(b0, multiplica3(_B, t1), 1);

        if (clampA0 || clampA1 || clampB0 || clampB1){
            if (t0 < 0 && clampA0)
                pA = a0;
            else if (t0 > norma3(A) && clampA1)
                pA = a1;
            if (t1 < 0 && clampB0)
                pB = b0;
            else if (t1 > norma3(B) && clampB1)
                pB = b1;
        }

        d = norma3(soma3(pA, pB, -1));

        rd->pA = pA;
        rd->pB = pB;
        rd->d = d;
    }

    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(cross);
    free(t);
    return rd;
}

int main(void){
    //example
    double a1[] = { 13.43, 21.77, 46.81 };
    double a0[] = { 27.83, 31.74, -26.60 };
    double b0[] = { 77.54, 7.53, 6.22 };
    double b1[] = { 26.99, 12.39, 11.18 };

    Result_distance* rd = closestDistanceBetweenLines(a0, a1, b0, b1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    printf("pA = [%f, %f, %f]\n", rd->pA[0], rd->pA[1], rd->pA[2]);
    printf("pB = [%f, %f, %f]\n", rd->pB[0], rd->pB[1], rd->pB[2]);
    printf("d = %f\n", rd->d);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For calculating the minimum distance between 2 2D line segments it is true that you have to perform 4 perpendicular distance from endpoint to other line checks successively using each of the 4 endpoints. However, if you find that the perpendicular line drawn out does not intersect the line segment in any of the 4 cases then you have to perform 4 additional endpoint to endpoint distance checks to find the shortest distance.

Whether there is a more elegent solution to this I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the above solutions are correct under the assumption that the line segments do not intersect! If the line segments intersect it is clear that their distance should be 0. It is therefore necessary to one final check which is: Suppose the distance between point A and CD, d(A,CD),  was the smallest of the 4 checks mentioned by Dean. Then take a small step along the segment AB from point A. Denote this point E. If d(E,CD) < d(A,CD), the segments must be intersecting! Note that this will never be the case addressed by Stephen.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic code I follow for the shortest distance between any two plan or any two points in the 3d plane it works well metrics can be changed for the given input

Code In PYTHON

```py
def dot(c1,c2):
        return c1[0]* c2[0] + c1[1] * c2[1] + c1[2] * c2[2]

 
def norm(c1):
    return math.sqrt(dot(c1, c1))


def getShortestDistance(x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,z1,z2,z3,z4):
    print(x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,z1,z2,z3,z4)
    EPS = 0.00000001
    delta21 = [1,2,3]
    delta21[0] = x2 - x1
    delta21[1] = y2 - y1
    delta21[2] = z2 - z1
 
    delta41 = [1,2,3]
    delta41[0] = x4 - x3
    delta41[1] = y4 - y3
    delta41[2] = z4 - z3
 
    delta13 = [1,2,3]
    delta13[0] = x1 - x3
    delta13[1] = y1 - y3
    delta13[2] = z1 - z3
 
    a = dot(delta21, delta21)
    b = dot(delta21, delta41)
    c = dot(delta41, delta41)
    d = dot(delta21, delta13)
    e = dot(delta41, delta13)
    D = a * c - b * b
 
    sc = D
    sN = D
    sD = D
    tc = D 
    tN = D  
    tD = D
 
    if D < EPS:
        sN = 0.0
        sD = 1.0
        tN = e
        tD = c
    else:
        sN = (b * e - c * d)
        tN = (a * e - b * d)
        if sN < 0.0:
            sN = 0.0
            tN = e
            tD = c
        elif sN > sD:
            sN = sD
            tN = e + b
            tD = c
 
    if tN < 0.0:
        tN = 0.0
        if -d < 0.0:
            sN = 0.0
        elif -d > a:
            sN = sD
        else:
            sN = -d
            sD = a

    elif tN > tD:
        tN = tD
        if ((-d + b) < 0.0):
            sN = 0
        elif ((-d + b) > a):
            sN = sD
        else:
            sN = (-d + b)
            sD = a
 
    if (abs(sN) < EPS):
        sc = 0.0
    else:
        sc = sN / sD
    if (abs(tN) < EPS):
        tc = 0.0
    else:
        tc = tN / tD
    
    dP = [1,2,3]
    dP[0] = delta13[0] + (sc * delta21[0]) - (tc * delta41[0])
    dP[1] = delta13[1] + (sc * delta21[1]) - (tc * delta41[1])
    dP[2] = delta13[2] + (sc * delta21[2]) - (tc * delta41[2])
 
    return math.sqrt(dot(dP, dP))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to compute the shortest distance between a large number of 3D lines.  The code from [Fnord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1429402/fnord) was a start, but it was for only a single batch.  I ported most of it to multi-batch, below.

```py
import numpy as np
import time

def closest_distance_between_lines(a0, a1, b0, b1):
    # equation for a line
    number_of_lines = a0.shape[0]

    A = a1 - a0
    B = b1 - b0

    # get the magnitude of each line
    magA = np.broadcast_to(np.expand_dims(np.linalg.norm(A, axis=1), axis=1), (number_of_lines, 3))
    magB = np.broadcast_to(np.expand_dims(np.linalg.norm(B, axis=1), axis=1), (number_of_lines, 3))

    # get the unit-normalized lines
    _A = A / magA
    _B = B / magB

    # get the perpendicular line
    cross = np.cross(_A, _B, axis=1)

    # normalize the perpendicular line
    denom = np.linalg.norm(cross, axis=1)**2

    # get the line between the start of the previous two lines 
    t = (b0 - a0)

    stacked_matrices_A = np.stack([t, _B, cross], axis=1)
    detA = np.linalg.det(stacked_matrices_A)

    stacked_matrices_B = np.stack([t, _A, cross], axis=1)
    detB = np.linalg.det(stacked_matrices_B)

    t0 = detA/denom
    t1 = detB/denom

    t0 = np.broadcast_to(np.expand_dims(t0, axis=1), (number_of_lines, 3))
    t1 = np.broadcast_to(np.expand_dims(t1, axis=1), (number_of_lines, 3))

    # get the points that represent the closest projected distance between the two lines
    pA = a0 + (_A * t0)
    pB = b0 + (_B * t1)

    return pA, pB, np.linalg.norm(pA-pB, axis=1)

number_of_samples = 10000000
a0 = np.random.rand(number_of_samples,3)
a1 = np.random.rand(number_of_samples,3)
b0 = np.random.rand(number_of_samples,3)
b1 = np.random.rand(number_of_samples,3)

start_time = time.time()
point_line_a, point_line_b, distance = closest_distance_between_lines(a0, a1, b0, b1)
end_time = time.time()

print("\nPoints pA on line A that are closest to line B with shape {}:\n{}".format(point_line_a.shape, point_line_a))
print("\nPoints pB on line B that are closest to line A with shape {}:\n{}".format(point_line_b.shape, point_line_b))
print("\nDistances between pA and pB with shape {}:\n{}".format(distance.shape, distance))
print("\n{:.2} seconds to compute closest distances between {:,} lines\n".format(end_time - start_time, number_of_samples))
```

Here is the output of above:

```bash
Points pA on line A that are closest to line B with shape (10000000, 3):
[[0.51075268 0.63261352 0.41417815]
 [0.88225225 0.41163515 0.06090485]
 [0.27712801 0.99045177 0.58932854]
 ...
 [0.25982217 0.11225041 0.79015618]
 [0.58653313 0.47864821 0.11680724]
 [0.38297058 0.2251661  1.11088736]]

Points pB on line B that are closest to line A with shape (10000000, 3):
[[0.5084189  0.42417817 0.5847618 ]
 [0.83041058 0.38914519 0.02384158]
 [0.26068716 0.98567827 0.5010647 ]
 ...
 [0.34356827 0.42162445 0.75820875]
 [0.44523571 0.40278146 0.0014156 ]
 [0.28498604 0.23670301 1.00712087]]

Distances between pA and pB with shape (10000000,):
[0.26935018 0.0675799  0.08990881 ... 0.32209679 0.19757518 0.14318364]

8.3 seconds to compute closest distances between 10,000,000 lines
```

Note, the code does not check for parallel lines, and it technically considers the entire line (rather than just the line segment).

To make it even faster, below is the same code ported to PyTorch:

```py
import torch
import time

device = torch.device('cuda:0') 

def closest_distance_between_lines(a0, a1, b0, b1):
    number_of_lines = a0.shape[0]

    # equation for a line
    A = a1 - a0
    B = b1 - b0

    # get the magnitude of each line
    magA = torch.broadcast_to(torch.unsqueeze(torch.linalg.norm(A, dim=1), dim=1), (number_of_lines, 3))
    magB = torch.broadcast_to(torch.unsqueeze(torch.linalg.norm(B, dim=1), dim=1), (number_of_lines, 3))

    # get the unit-normalized lines
    _A = A / magA
    _B = B / magB

    # get the perpendicular line
    cross = torch.cross(_A, _B, dim=1)

    # normalize the perpendicular line
    denom = torch.linalg.norm(cross, dim=1)**2
    
    # get the line between the start of the previous two lines 
    t = (b0 - a0)

    stacked_matrices_A = torch.stack([t, _B, cross], dim=1)
    detA = torch.linalg.det(stacked_matrices_A)

    stacked_matrices_B = torch.stack([t, _A, cross], dim=1)
    detB = torch.linalg.det(stacked_matrices_B)

    t0 = detA / denom
    t1 = detB / denom

    t0 = torch.broadcast_to(torch.unsqueeze(t0, dim=1), (number_of_lines, 3))
    t1 = torch.broadcast_to(torch.unsqueeze(t1, dim=1), (number_of_lines, 3))

    # get the points that represent the closest projected distance between the two lines
    pA = a0 + (_A * t0)
    pB = b0 + (_B * t1)

    return pA, pB, torch.linalg.norm(pA-pB, dim=1)

number_of_samples = 10000000

a0 = torch.rand(number_of_samples,3).to(device=device)
a1 = torch.rand(number_of_samples,3).to(device=device)
b0 = torch.rand(number_of_samples,3).to(device=device)
b1 = torch.rand(number_of_samples,3).to(device=device)

start_time = time.time()
point_line_a, point_line_b, distance = closest_distance_between_lines(a0, a1, b0, b1)
end_time = time.time()

print("\nPoints pA on line A that are closest to line B with shape {}:\n{}".format(point_line_a.shape, point_line_a))
print("\nPoints pB on line B that are closest to line A with shape {}:\n{}".format(point_line_b.shape, point_line_b))
print("\nDistances between pA and pB with shape {}:\n{}".format(distance.shape, distance))
print("\n{:.2} seconds to compute closest distances between {:,} lines\n".format(end_time - start_time, number_of_samples))
```

On my GPU, the runtime from NumPy to Torch speeds up from 8.3 seconds to 0.13 seconds.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is in essence the one from Alex Martelli, but I've added a Point and a LineSegment class to make reading easier. I also adjusted the formatting and added some tests.

The line segment intersection is wrong, but it seems not to matter for the calculation of the distance of line segments. If you're interested in a correct line segment intersection thest, look here: [How do you detect whether or not two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15001181/562769)

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Calculate the distance between line segments."""

import math


class Point(object):
    """A two dimensional point."""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)


class LineSegment(object):
    """A line segment in a two dimensional space."""
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        assert isinstance(p1, Point), \
            "p1 is not of type Point, but of %r" % type(p1)
        assert isinstance(p2, Point), \
            "p2 is not of type Point, but of %r" % type(p2)
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2


def segments_distance(segment1, segment2):
    """Calculate the distance between two line segments in the plane.

    >>> a = LineSegment(Point(1,0), Point(2,0))
    >>> b = LineSegment(Point(0,1), Point(0,2))
    >>> "%0.2f" % segments_distance(a, b)
    '1.41'
    >>> c = LineSegment(Point(0,0), Point(5,5))
    >>> d = LineSegment(Point(2,2), Point(4,4))
    >>> e = LineSegment(Point(2,2), Point(7,7))
    >>> "%0.2f" % segments_distance(c, d)
    '0.00'
    >>> "%0.2f" % segments_distance(c, e)
    '0.00'
    """
    if segments_intersect(segment1, segment2):
        return 0
    # try each of the 4 vertices w/the other segment
    distances = []
    distances.append(point_segment_distance(segment1.p1, segment2))
    distances.append(point_segment_distance(segment1.p2, segment2))
    distances.append(point_segment_distance(segment2.p1, segment1))
    distances.append(point_segment_distance(segment2.p2, segment1))
    return min(distances)


def segments_intersect(segment1, segment2):
    """Check if two line segments in the plane intersect.
    >>> segments_intersect(LineSegment(Point(0,0), Point(1,0)), \
                           LineSegment(Point(0,0), Point(1,0)))
    True
    """
    dx1 = segment1.p2.x - segment1.p1.x
    dy1 = segment1.p2.y - segment1.p2.y
    dx2 = segment2.p2.x - segment2.p1.x
    dy2 = segment2.p2.y - segment2.p1.y
    delta = dx2 * dy1 - dy2 * dx1
    if delta == 0:  # parallel segments
        # TODO: Could be (partially) identical!
        return False
    s = (dx1 * (segment2.p1.y - segment1.p1.y) +
         dy1 * (segment1.p1.x - segment2.p1.x)) / delta
    t = (dx2 * (segment1.p1.y - segment2.p1.y) +
         dy2 * (segment2.p1.x - segment1.p1.x)) / (-delta)
    return (0 <= s <= 1) and (0 <= t <= 1)


def point_segment_distance(point, segment):
    """
    >>> a = LineSegment(Point(1,0), Point(2,0))
    >>> b = LineSegment(Point(2,0), Point(0,2))
    >>> point_segment_distance(Point(0,0), a)
    1.0
    >>> "%0.2f" % point_segment_distance(Point(0,0), b)
    '1.41'
    """
    assert isinstance(point, Point), \
        "point is not of type Point, but of %r" % type(point)
    dx = segment.p2.x - segment.p1.x
    dy = segment.p2.y - segment.p1.y
    if dx == dy == 0:  # the segment's just a point
        return math.hypot(point.x - segment.p1.x, point.y - segment.p1.y)

    if dx == 0:
        if (point.y <= segment.p1.y or point.y <= segment.p2.y) and \
           (point.y >= segment.p2.y or point.y >= segment.p2.y):
            return abs(point.x - segment.p1.x)

    if dy == 0:
        if (point.x <= segment.p1.x or point.x <= segment.p2.x) and \
           (point.x >= segment.p2.x or point.x >= segment.p2.x):
            return abs(point.y - segment.p1.y)

    # Calculate the t that minimizes the distance.
    t = ((point.x - segment.p1.x) * dx + (point.y - segment.p1.y) * dy) / \
        (dx * dx + dy * dy)

    # See if this represents one of the segment's
    # end points or a point in the middle.
    if t < 0:
        dx = point.x - segment.p1.x
        dy = point.y - segment.p1.y
    elif t > 1:
        dx = point.x - segment.p2.x
        dy = point.y - segment.p2.y
    else:
        near_x = segment.p1.x + t * dx
        near_y = segment.p1.y + t * dy
        dx = point.x - near_x
        dy = point.y - near_y

    return math.hypot(dx, dy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a Swift port based on Pratik Deoghare's answer above.  Pratik references Dan Sunday's excellent write-up and code examples found here: http://geomalgorithms.com/a07-_distance.html

The following functions calculate the minimum distance between two lines or two line segments, and is a direct port of Dan Sunday's C++ examples.

The LASwift linear algebra package is used to do the matrix and vector calculations.

```swift
//
// This is a Swift port of the C++ code here 
// http://geomalgorithms.com/a07-_distance.html
//
// Copyright 2001 softSurfer, 2012 Dan Sunday
// This code may be freely used, distributed and modified for any purpose
// providing that this copyright notice is included with it.
// SoftSurfer makes no warranty for this code, and cannot be held
// liable for any real or imagined damage resulting from its use.
// Users of this code must verify correctness for their application.
//
//
// LASwift is a "Linear Algebra library for Swift language" by Alexander Taraymovich
// https://github.com/AlexanderTar/LASwift
// LASwift is available under the BSD-3-Clause license.
//
// I've modified the lineToLineDistance and segmentToSegmentDistance functions
// to also return the points on each line/segment where the distance is shortest.
//
import LASwift
import Foundation

func norm(_ v: Vector) -> Double {
    return sqrt(dot(v,v))  // norm = length of  vector
}

func d(_ u: Vector, _ v: Vector) -> Double {
    return norm(u-v)        // distance = norm of difference
}

let SMALL_NUM = 0.000000000000000001  // anything that avoids division overflow

typealias Point = Vector

struct Line {
    let P0: Point
    let P1: Point
}

struct Segment {
    let P0: Point
    let P1: Point
}

// lineToLineDistance(): get the 3D minimum distance between 2 lines
//    Input:  two 3D lines L1 and L2
//    Return: the shortest distance between L1 and L2
func lineToLineDistance(L1: Line, L2: Line) -> (P1: Point, P2: Point, D: Double) {
    let u = L1.P1 - L1.P0
    let v = L2.P1 - L2.P0
    let w = L1.P0 - L2.P0
    let a = dot(u,u)         // always >= 0
    let b = dot(u,v)
    let c = dot(v,v)         // always >= 0
    let d = dot(u,w)
    let e = dot(v,w)
    let D = a*c - b*b        // always >= 0
    var sc, tc: Double

    // compute the line parameters of the two closest points
    if D < SMALL_NUM {  // the lines are almost parallel
        sc = 0.0
        tc = b>c ? d/b : e/c    // use the largest denominator
    }
    else {
        sc = (b*e - c*d) / D
        tc = (a*e - b*d) / D
    }

    // get the difference of the two closest points
    let dP = w + (sc .* u) - (tc .* v)  // =  L1(sc) - L2(tc)

    let Psc = L1.P0 + sc .* u
    let Qtc = L2.P0 + tc .* v
    let dP2 = Psc - Qtc
    assert(dP == dP2)

    return (P1: Psc, P2: Qtc, D: norm(dP))   // return the closest distance
}

// segmentToSegmentDistance(): get the 3D minimum distance between 2 segments
//    Input:  two 3D line segments S1 and S2
//    Return: the shortest distance between S1 and S2
func segmentToSegmentDistance(S1: Segment, S2: Segment) -> (P1: Point, P2: Point, D: Double) {
    let u = S1.P1 - S1.P0
    let v = S2.P1 - S2.P0
    let w = S1.P0 - S2.P0
    let a = dot(u,u)         // always >= 0
    let b = dot(u,v)
    let c = dot(v,v)         // always >= 0
    let d = dot(u,w)
    let e = dot(v,w)
    let D = a*c - b*b        // always >= 0
    let sc: Double
    var sN: Double
    var sD = D               // sc = sN / sD, default sD = D >= 0
    let tc: Double
    var tN: Double
    var tD = D               // tc = tN / tD, default tD = D >= 0

    // compute the line parameters of the two closest points
    if (D < SMALL_NUM) { // the lines are almost parallel
        sN = 0.0         // force using point P0 on segment S1
        sD = 1.0         // to prevent possible division by 0.0 later
        tN = e
        tD = c
    }
    else {                 // get the closest points on the infinite lines
        sN = (b*e - c*d)
        tN = (a*e - b*d)
        if (sN < 0.0) {        // sc < 0 => the s=0 edge is visible
            sN = 0.0
            tN = e
            tD = c
        }
        else if (sN > sD) {  // sc > 1  => the s=1 edge is visible
            sN = sD
            tN = e + b
            tD = c
        }
    }

    if (tN < 0.0) {            // tc < 0 => the t=0 edge is visible
        tN = 0.0
        // recompute sc for this edge
        if (-d < 0.0) {
            sN = 0.0
        }
        else if (-d > a) {
            sN = sD
        }
        else {
            sN = -d
            sD = a
        }
    }
    else if (tN > tD) {      // tc > 1  => the t=1 edge is visible
        tN = tD;
        // recompute sc for this edge
        if ((-d + b) < 0.0) {
            sN = 0
        }
        else if ((-d + b) > a) {
            sN = sD
        }
        else {
            sN = (-d +  b)
            sD = a
        }
    }
    // finally do the division to get sc and tc
    sc = (abs(sN) < SMALL_NUM ? 0.0 : sN / sD)
    tc = (abs(tN) < SMALL_NUM ? 0.0 : tN / tD)

    // get the difference of the two closest points
    let dP = w + (sc .* u) - (tc .* v)  // =  S1(sc) - S2(tc)

    let Psc = S1.P0 + sc .* u
    let Qtc = S2.P0 + tc .* v
    let dP2 = Psc - Qtc
    assert(dP == dP2)

    return (P1: Psc, P2: Qtc, D: norm(dP))   // return the closest distance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Java solution (done the easy way with point checking, so probably not as efficient):

```java
public static double getDistanceBetweenLineSegments(
        PointDouble line1Start, PointDouble line1End,
        PointDouble line2Start, PointDouble line2End) {
    double result = 0;

    // If they don't intersect, then work out the distance
    if (!isLineIntersectingLine(line1Start, line1End, line2Start, line2End)) {
        double p1 = getDistanceBetweenPointAndLine(line1Start, line2Start, line2End);
        double p2 = getDistanceBetweenPointAndLine(line1End, line2Start, line2End);
        double p3 = getDistanceBetweenPointAndLine(line2Start, line1Start, line1End);
        double p4 = getDistanceBetweenPointAndLine(line2End, line1Start, line1End);
        
        result = MathSafe.min(p1, MathSafe.min(p2, MathSafe.min(p3, p4)));
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

And all the other code you need:

```java
public class PointDouble {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public PointDouble(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

```java
private static int relativeCCW(
        double x1, double y1,
        double x2, double y2,
        double px, double py) {
    x2 -= x1;
    y2 -= y1;
    px -= x1;
    py -= y1;
    double ccw = px * y2 - py * x2;

    if (ccw == 0.0) {
        ccw = px * x2 + py * y2;

        if (ccw > 0.0) {
            px -= x2;
            py -= y2;
            ccw = px * x2 + py * y2;

            if (ccw < 0.0) {
                ccw = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }
    return (ccw < 0.0) ? -1 : ((ccw > 0.0) ? 1 : 0);
}

public static boolean isLineIntersectingLine(
        PointDouble line1Start, PointDouble line1End,
        PointDouble line2Start, PointDouble line2End) {
    return (
            (relativeCCW(line1Start.getX(), line1Start.getY(), line1End.getX(), line1End.getY(), line2Start.getX(), line2Start.getY()) *
                    relativeCCW(line1Start.getX(), line1Start.getY(), line1End.getX(), line1End.getY(), line2End.getX(), line2End.getY()) <= 0)
            &&
            (relativeCCW(line2Start.getX(), line2Start.getY(), line2End.getX(), line2End.getY(), line1Start.getX(), line1Start.getY()) *
                    relativeCCW(line2Start.getX(), line2Start.getY(), line2End.getX(), line2End.getY(), line1End.getX(), line1End.getY()) <= 0));
}

public static double getDistanceBetweenPointAndLine(PointDouble pt, PointDouble linePt1, PointDouble linePt2) {
    double lineX = linePt2.getX() - linePt1.getX();
    double lineY = linePt2.getY() - linePt1.getY();
    double dot = (pt.getX() - linePt1.getX()) * lineX + (pt.getY() - linePt1.getY()) * lineY;
    double len_sq = lineX * lineX + lineY * lineY;
    double param = -1;
    double xx;
    double yy;
    
    if (len_sq != 0) {
        param = dot / len_sq;
    }

    if (param < 0) {
        xx = linePt1.getX();
        yy = linePt1.getY();
    }
    else if (param > 1) {
        xx = linePt2.getX();
        yy = linePt2.getY();
    }
    else {
        xx = linePt1.getX() + param * lineX;
        yy = linePt1.getY() + param * lineY;
    }

    return MathSafe.hypot(pt.getX() - xx, pt.getY() - yy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in perl with a few differences from Fnord's:

- It always clamps (add non-clamping behavior flags, if you wish, by following Fnord's example).
- It catches lines of zero-length line segments that would otherwise cause a divide by zero.
- The `1e-6` values below are used to deal with possible floating point errors.   Adjust or remove those if you need a different tolerance:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::Vector::Real;
use Math::Matrix;

# True if $a >= $b within $tolerance
sub approx_greater
{
    my ($a, $b, $tolerance) = @_;

    $tolerance //= 1e-6;

    return ($a-$b) > -$tolerance;
}

# True if $a <= $b within $tolerance
sub approx_lesser
{
    my ($a, $b, $tolerance) = @_;

    $tolerance //= 1e-6;

    return ($b-$a) > -$tolerance;
}

# True if $a == $b within $tolerance
sub approx_equal
{
    my ($a, $b, $tolerance) = @_;

    $tolerance //= 1e-6;

    return abs($a-$b) < $tolerance;
}


# Returns shortest line: [ [x1,y1,z1], [x2,y2,z2], distance ].  
# If askew lines cross (or nearly-intersect) then xyz1 and xyz2 are undefined
# and only distance is returned.
#
# Thank you to @Fnord: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18994296/14055985
sub line_intersect
{
    # Map @_ as vectors:
    my ($a0, $a1, $b0, $b1) = map { V(@{ $_ }) } @_;

    my $A = ($a1-$a0);
    my $B = ($b1-$b0);

    my $magA = abs($A);
    my $magB = abs($B);

    # If length line segment:
    if ($magA == 0 || $magB == 0)
    {
        return V(undef, undef, 0);
    }

    my $_A = $A / $magA;
    my $_B = $B / $magB;

    my $cross = $_A x $_B;
    my $denom = $cross->norm2;

    # If lines are parallel (denom=0) test if lines overlap.
    # If they don't overlap then there is a closest point solution.
    # If they do overlap, there are infinite closest positions, but there is a closest distance
    #if ($denom == 0)
    if (approx_equal($denom, 0))
    {
        my $d0 = $_A * ($b0-$a0);
        my $d1 = $_A * ($b1-$a0);

        # Is segment B before A?
        #if ($d0 <= 0 && 0 >= $d1)
        if (approx_lesser($d0, 0) && approx_greater(0, $d1))
        {
            if (abs($d0) < abs($d1))
            {
                return V($a0, $b0, abs($a0-$b0));
            }
            else
            {
                return V($a0, $b1, abs($a0-$b1));
            }
        }
        # Is segment B after A?
        #elsif ($d0 >= $magA && $magA <= $d1)
        elsif (approx_greater($d0, $magA) && approx_lesser($magA, $d1))
        {
            if (abs($d0) < abs($d1))
            {
                return V($a1, $b0, abs($a1-$b0));
            }
            else
            {
                return V($a1, $b1, abs($a1-$b1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            # Segments overlap, return distance between parallel segments
            return V(V(), V(), abs((($d0*$_A)+$a0)-$b0));
        }

    }
    else
    {
        # Lines criss-cross: Calculate the projected closest points
        my $t = ($b0 - $a0);

        # Math::Matrix won't wirth with Math::Vector::Real
        # even though they are blessed arrays, 
        # so convert them to arrays and back to refs:
        my $detA = Math::Matrix->new([ [ @$t ], [ @$_B ], [ @$cross] ])->det;
        my $detB = Math::Matrix->new([ [ @$t ], [ @$_A ], [ @$cross] ])->det;

        my $t0 = $detA / $denom;
        my $t1 = $detB / $denom;

        my $pA = $a0 + ($_A * $t0); # Projected closest point on segment A
        my $pB = $b0 + ($_B * $t1); # Projected closest point on segment A

        if ($t0 < 0)
        {
            $pA = $a0;
        }
        elsif ($t0 > $magA)
        {
            $pA = $a1;
        }

        if ($t1 < 0)
        {
            $pB = $b0;
        }
        elsif ($t1 > $magB)
        {
            $pB = $b1;
        }

        # Clamp projection A
        if ($t0 < 0 || $t0 > $magA)
        {
            my $dot = $_B * ($pA-$b0);
            if ($dot < 0)
            {
                $dot = 0;
            }
            elsif ($dot > $magB)
            {
                $dot = $magB;
            }

            $pB = $b0 + ($_B * $dot)
        }
        
        # Clamp projection B
        if ($t1 < 0 || $t1 > $magB)
        {
            my $dot = $_A * ($pB-$a0);
            if ($dot < 0)
            {
                $dot = 0;
            }
            elsif ($dot > $magA)
            {
                $dot = $magA;
            }

            $pA = $a0 + ($_A * $dot)
        }

        return V($pA, $pB, abs($pA-$pB));
    }
}

print "example: " . line_intersect(
    [13.43,  21.77,  46.81  ],  [27.83,  31.74,  -26.60  ],
    [77.54,  7.53,   6.22   ],  [26.99,  12.39,  11.18   ])  .  "\n"  ;

print "contiguous: " . line_intersect(
    [0, 0, 0  ],  [ 0, 0, 1  ],
    [0, 0, 1  ],  [ 0, 0, 2  ],
    )  .  "\n"  ;

print "contiguous 90: " . line_intersect(
    [0, 0, 0  ],  [ 0, 0, 1  ],
    [0, 0, 1  ],  [ 0, 1, 1  ],
    )  .  "\n"  ;

print "colinear separate: " . line_intersect(
    [0, 0, 0  ],  [ 0, 0, 1  ],
    [0, 0, 2  ],  [ 0, 0, 3  ],
    )  .  "\n"  ;

print "cross: " . line_intersect(
    [1, 1, 0  ],  [ -1, -1, 0  ],
    [-1, 1, 0  ],  [ 1, -1, 0  ],
    )  .  "\n"  ;

print "cross+z: " . line_intersect(
    [1, 1, 0  ],  [ -1, -1, 0  ],
    [-1, 1, 1  ],  [ 1, -1, 1  ],
    )  .  "\n"  ;

print "full overlap1: " . line_intersect(
    [2, 0, 0  ],  [ 5, 0, 0  ],
    [3, 0, 0  ],  [ 4, 0, 0  ],
    )  .  "\n"  ;

print "full overlap2: " . line_intersect(
    [3, 0, 0  ],  [ 4, 0, 0  ],
    [2, 0, 0  ],  [ 5, 0, 0  ],
    )  .  "\n"  ;

print "partial overlap1: " . line_intersect(
    [2, 0, 0  ],  [ 5, 0, 0  ],
    [3, 0, 0  ],  [ 6, 0, 0  ],
    )  .  "\n"  ;

print "partial overlap2: " . line_intersect(
    [3, 0, 0  ],  [ 6, 0, 0  ],
    [2, 0, 0  ],  [ 5, 0, 0  ],
    )  .  "\n"  ;

print "parallel: " . line_intersect(
    [3, 0, 0  ],  [ 6, 0, 0  ],
    [3, 0, 1  ],  [ 6, 0, 1  ],
    )  .  "\n"  ;
```

#### Output

```json
    example: {{20.29994361624, 26.5264817954106, 11.7875999397098}, {26.99, 12.39, 11.18}, 15.6513944955904}
    contiguous: {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, 0}
    contiguous 90: {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, 0}
    colinear separate: {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 2}, 1}
    cross: {{-2.22044604925031e-16, -2.22044604925031e-16, 0}, {2.22044604925031e-16, -2.22044604925031e-16, 0}, 4.44089209850063e-16}
    cross+z: {{-2.22044604925031e-16, -2.22044604925031e-16, 0}, {2.22044604925031e-16, -2.22044604925031e-16, 1}, 1}
    full overlap1: {{}, {}, 0}
    full overlap2: {{}, {}, 0}
    partial overlap1: {{}, {}, 0}
    partial overlap2: {{}, {}, 0}
    parallel: {{}, {}, 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution from Fnord just for Ray-Ray Intersection in c# (infinite Lines, not Line segments)
It requires System.Numerics.Vector3

```
     public static (Vector3 pointRayA, Vector3 pointRayB) ClosestPointRayRay((Vector3 point, Vector3 dir) rayA,
        (Vector3 point, Vector3 dir) rayB)
    {
        var a = Normalize(rayA.dir);
        var b = Normalize(rayB.dir);
        var cross = Vector3.Cross(a, b);
        var crossMag = cross.Length();
        var denominator = crossMag * crossMag; 

        var t = rayB.point - rayA.point;
        var detA = new Matrix3X3(t, b, cross).Det;
        var detB = new Matrix3X3(t, a, cross).Det;

        var t0 = detA / denominator;
        var t1 = detB / denominator;

        var pa = rayA.point + (a * t0);
        var pb = rayB.point + (b * t1);
        return (pa, pb);
    }


public struct Matrix3X3
    {
        private float a11, a12, a13, a21, a22, a23, a31, a32, a33;

        public Matrix3X3(Vector3 col1, Vector3 col2, Vector3 col3)
        {
            a11 = col1.X;
            a21 = col1.Y;
            a31 = col1.Z;

            a12 = col2.X;
            a22 = col2.Y;
            a32 = col2.Z;

            a13 = col3.X;
            a23 = col3.Y;
            a33 = col3.Z;
        }

        public float Det =>
            a11 * a22 * a33 + a12 * a23 * a31 + a13 * a21 * a32 -
            (a31 * a22 * a13 + a32 * a23 * a11 + a33 * a21 * a12);
    }
```

it returns the closest point on RayA to RayB ,named pointRayA, and vice versa.
A short test:

```
       [Test]
    public void RayRayIntersection()
    {
        var lineABase = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        var lineADir = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
      
        var lineBBase = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
        var lineBDir = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

        var res = ClosestPointRayRay((lineABase, lineADir), (lineBBase, lineBDir));
        Console.WriteLine(res);

    }
```

returns `(<0, 0, 0>, <1, 0, 0>)`

Answer (score 0):

The top answers looked too complex so I've decided to implement a short script in Python/Blender to calculate the shortest distance between two segmented identified by two 2D extremity points. It's based on the rationale that the orthogonal projection is the shortest distance, as follows:

- Calculate the projected point of each extremity point on the opposite segment.
- If the projected point belongs to the opposite segment, calculate the distance between the point & its projection. Otherwise consider this distance to be infinite.
- Stop here if the smallest distance of the four projections isn't infinite.
- Otherwise, the distance between the two segments is equal to the shortest distance between extremity points (1st point from 1st segment and 2nd one from the 2nd segment).

See [this python implementation](https://gist.github.com/h4k1m0u/7a7cfd060299dbe8835d53ec2eb8f997).

Answer (score 0):

A C# implementation based on the concise and elegant Lua implementation by @TreyReynolds above and using *System.Numerics.Vector3*.

```cs
private static Line ShortestBridge(Line a, Line b, bool clamp = true) 
{
  if (a.Length == 0 || b.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("The supplied lines must not have a length of zero!");

  var eta = 1e-6;
  var r = b.From - a.From;
  var u = a.To - a.From;
  var v = b.To - b.From;
  var ru = Vector3.Dot(r, u);
  var rv = Vector3.Dot(r, v);
  var uu = Vector3.Dot(u, u);
  var uv = Vector3.Dot(u, v);
  var vv = Vector3.Dot(v, v);
  var det = uu * vv - uv * uv;

  float s, t;
  if (det < eta * uu * vv) {
    s = OptionalClamp01(ru / uu, clamp);
    t = 0;
  } else {
    s = OptionalClamp01((ru * vv - rv * uv) / det, clamp);
    t = OptionalClamp01((ru * uv - rv * uu) / det, clamp);
  }

  var S = OptionalClamp01((t * uv + ru) / uu, clamp);
  var T = OptionalClamp01((s * uv - rv) / vv, clamp);

  var A = a.From + S * u;
  var B = b.From + T * v;
  return new Line(A, B);
}

private static float OptionalClamp01(float value, bool clamp)
{
    if (!clamp) return value;
    if (value >1) return 1;
    if (value <0) return 0;
    return value;
}
```

If you aren't using a library with a Line class then this is just about the simplest implementation that you can extend as required...

```cs
  using System.Numerics;
  
  public class Line
    {
        public Line(Vector3 _From, Vector3 _To)
        {
            From=_From;
            To=_To;
        }
        public Vector3 From {get;}
        public Vector3 To {get;}
        public float Length => (To-From).Length();
    }
```

Test or use as follows:

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
        // define line 1
        var a = new Vector3(-10,-10, 10);
        var b = new Vector3(10,10,10);
        var l1 = new Line(a,b);     
        
        // define line 2
        var c = new Vector3(5,0,3);
        var d = new Vector3(6,3,-1);
        var l2 = new Line(c,d); 
        
        // get shortest bridging line between them
        var result = ShortestBridge(l1,l2);             
        Console.WriteLine($"bridge is from {result.From}, to {result.To}.");
    }
```